# кнопка radio работает не правильно

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться с задачей.
На сайте есть кнопка "Изменить" при нажатии на неё происходит загрузка и открывается окно (не обновляя страницы), в этом окне есть несколько радиокнопок управляет кнопками javascript:

```
    <script>
function Product_List(a,b) {
    $('.pop_up .pop_up_content .content').html('<b>Загружаем информацию...</b><br><br><img src="./images/load.gif" alt="Загрузка страницы">');
    $('.pop_up .pop_up_content .content').load('./page/price_list.php', {name:a, cat:b}, function(){
        $('.pop_up .pop_up_content').css({'max-width':'650px'});
    });
};
function Product_Select(a,b,c) {
    $('span.select_name[data-name-select="'+c+'"]').text($(a).text());
    $('span.select_name[data-name-select="'+c+'"]').attr('data-id', b);
    var p_img=$(a).parent().children(":first").attr('src');
    var p_img=p_img.match( /\d+\.png/i );
    $('span.select_name[data-name-select="'+c+'"]').attr('data-img', p_img[0]);
    $('span.select_edit[data-name-fields="'+c+'"]').text('Изменить');
    $('.pop_up').css({'display':'none'});
    $('.pop_up .pop_up_content .content').html("");
    calculator();
};
</script>
```

Первая функция срабатывает полностью, вторая частично.
А именно:
В таком виде как есть радиокнопки работают но нет переключателя, а только кружек в котором он должен быть.
По идее нажатая кнопка закрывает окно, делает действие которое отображается на странице, а при последующем нажатии на кнопку "Изменить", радиокнопка остается на выбранной ранее позиции.

Если убрать из второй функции строки:

```
$('.pop_up').css({'display':'none'});
$('.pop_up .pop_up_content .content').html("");
```

то радиокнопка работает полностью и действие применяется и переключатель скачет из кружка в кружек , но окно не убирается.
Еще добавлю, при убранных строках из второй функции.
Можно окно закрыть в ручную крестом, окно убирается результат работы радиокнопки остается на сайте нужный, но при повторном нажатии на кнопку "Изменить" положение радиокнопки пропадает.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Какие окна, какие радиокнопки? Где они?